# Extracting different specified words from a particular string

Tags: r, string, excel-formula

I have a column in my excel which i want to modify.
Ill be needing the following

If a particular column has words like "CAP","Caps","caps","Cap","cap","CAPS" then an empty column should say "caps" or else "Default".

For Example:

Description                             Type
Cap for DPRD                            caps
Pickup cap change GLS criticality>  caps
Raise Caps for CGN9                 caps
Place TT Pads on DHL Lanes          Default
Noncon Caps for MXP8                    caps

I am working in excel and not sure if this can be acheived through excel or with R.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grepl` for a base R option:

```
df$label <- ifelse(grepl("caps?", df$col, ignore.case=TRUE), "caps", "Default")
```